# Karma test failing : TypeError: this.cardManagementService.getLabelList(...).replace is not a function

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am getting Karma error :

> TypeError: this.cardManagementService.getLabelList(...).replace is
> not a function

Please check my code in TS and Spec file. I think I am making some mistake while writing **usevalue** for **CardManagementService**.

*in TS file I have below code:*

```
 setCardManagementLabels(): void {
        this.cardManagementLabels.cardNumber = this.cardManagementService.getLabelList('PROFILE.CARDMGMTTAB.CARDNUM');
    
 .---Some code here --- 
    this.cardManagementService.getLabelList('PROFILE.CARDMGMTTAB.SUSPENDMESSAGENOCOVERAGE')
            .replace('{suspended}', 'suspended').replace('{suspended}', 'suspended')....................}}
```

*For spec file I have this :*

```
providers: [ ........{provide: CardManagementService, useValue: {getLabelList: () => of([]), getEventV: () => of([])} },......]

    fit('should test setCardManagementLabels method for suspend and no coverage reason', () => {
          component.cardStatus = 'Suspended';
          component.debitCardSuspendClosedReason = 'NO_COVERAGE';
          component.setCardManagementLabels();
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `useValue` at the `providers` of a test you need to provide a mock instance, that has the methods from the covered code. As `of([])` is returned by `getLabelList()` in the test, that does not have any method called `replace`.

I assume that `this.cardManagementService.getLabelList()` returns a string in the original code, so in your case `useValue: {getLabelList: () => "a string mocked string"` could by a good starting point.

Comment: thanks worked for me

Comment: Please consider acepting the answer ;)

Comment: this.titleService.setTitle(this.loginService.userDetails.clientTitle + ' Profile | Card Management
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
{ provide: LoginService, useValue: {clientTitle :  "a string mocked string" }},
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientTitle')
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Any idea to resolve this ?

Comment: `userDetails` is most probably undefined, it needs to be mocked with an object, that has `clientTitle` as a property. So `useValue: {userDetails: { clientTitle: "a string mocked string" }}` probably, but I'm not sure, if I interpreted it well.